# developing web part for sharepoint online with visual studio without local sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2015

Iam trying to develop webpart for firm website on SharePoint with visual studio, the problem is that there is no solution for SharePoint online - Visual web part. When i try to create SharePoint 2013 - visual web part, I get an 
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x56UP.png).

The only thing there is for Sharepoint online is Apps for Sharepoint and that isn't a web part, or atleast I haven't found a way to use it as such.

When I talk to my supervisor about the error, he tells me that they can't create a virtual server for me to install the SharePoint server on and I have to code it through the Sharepoint online.

Is there any way for me to develop and deploy the webpart with an online Sharepoint server instead of local one or to atleast create it through the apps for Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use App Parts, those are Web Parts that display content from an installed App, you can add them at any page of your site as normal Web Parts, App Parts are deployed in the same package as your App, so you can have everything in the same solution.

There are plenty of resources that will help you to develop Apps and to include App Parts also, just look for the right concept in google and you will find it.

There are two kinds of SharePoint Apps (or Add-ins which is the new name), the first one is **SharePoint Hosted** App and the second one is SharePoint **Provider Hosted** App, the one you need will depend on the functionality you want to achieve, but as a general reference you can think on the data source that you want to consume in your solution, e.g. if the data to be used by the App is in the SP Site where you are going to install it, then all you need is a SharePoint Hosted App, however if the data is in an external location like databases stored in local servers, then you will need SharePoint Provider Hosted App. Of course this is just a very basic view of this topic, there are other reasons to use one or the other but its pointless to make a full list here. This is a wide topic and you can find tons of articles and guides about this.

If all you need is a simple webpart to display some content with a nice look or roll up some content and provide an output based on it, then you can use a SharePoint Hosted App, which is the easiest to develop and deploy, with this kind of app you can use JavaScript get the data from your site, and then you can display your output in an App Part.

I'm sorry to not provide specific pages to read, but that's just because it's better to look for the guides that be easier for you to understand and that may vary from person to person, all you need to know is the concepts and topics to search for.

If you want me to help you with this please send me a message ([my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4713274/isaac-e-krauss?tab=profile)).